Proving that $L(\mu,\nu)$ is a metric on the space of measures with bounded support and total mass of 1
Let $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{M}^1$ where $\mathcal{M}^1$ denotes the space of Borel regular measures with bounded support and total mass of $1$ and $\phi\in\mathcal{C}_b$. Let $\mu\colon\mathcal{C}_b\to[0,\infty)$ be defined as $\mu(\phi)=\int\phi d\mu$ and $L(\mu,\nu)=\sup(\mu(\phi)-\nu(\phi)\mid\phi:X\to\mathbb{R},\text{Lip}(\phi)\leq 1)$. Prove that $L$ is a metric.
Non-negativity is straightforward. If $\mu=\nu$, then obviously the supremum is $0$. However, I didn't get the other direction. Symmetry holds since $\mu(\phi)-\nu(\phi)=-(\nu(\phi)-\mu(\phi))$. And the triangle inequality is always the hardest to show. Am I right so far? Can anyone help with the rest?
